# Why does this run every project regardless of what the user inputs?

Tags: python

Every time i run this code every method runs in order of 1-6, it should just run the project that's equal to the number the user inputs and i'm not sure how to fix it

```
    def runProgram():
        separate()
        # asks user a promt and has a set max value for their input
        run = getValidInput("\nWould you like to run this program? Yes(1) No(2) > > > ", 2)
        if run == 1:
            projectMapping = {1: assignmentOne(), 2: assignmentTwo(), 
            3: assignmentThree(), 4: assignmentFour(), 5: quadratic()}
            project = projectMapping.get(userInput)
            project()
            separate()
        if run == 2:
            # Restarts main loop, can't use continue since the method is outside the loop
            global main
            main = 0
            main = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling all the functions when you create the `projectMapping` dictionary. You should leave out `()` so you create a dictionary of functions. Then call the function after fetching from the dictionary.

```
        if run == 1:
            projectMapping = {
                1: assignmentOne, 2: assignmentTwo, 
                3: assignmentThree, 4: assignmentFour, 5: quadratic
            }
            project = projectMapping[userInput]
            project()
            separate()
```

Comment: I realize the irony in saying it repeatedly, but please read [answer] and do not answer duplicate questions. You should well understand by now that simple problems like this are almost always something that has come up before.